# AngularJS display AM/PM marker in lowercase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm using AngularJS's [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to format a time stamp.  It's working pretty well but I'd like to display the AM/PM marker (`a`) as lower case.

This is my expression:

```
{{item.date | date: 'h:mma, dd MMM y'}}
```

And this is the output from it:

> 9:00PM, 03 Jan 2017

I would like it to be:

> 9:00pm, 03 Jan 2017

Answer (score 5):

Piping the entire date to Angular's `lowercase`, as suggested in the other answer will, convert a date from 'Jan 18th, 1:00PM' to 'jan 18th, 1:00pm' ([pointed out by Holly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470305/angularjs-display-am-pm-marker-in-lowercase#comment70146907_41470320)). Not ideal. This solved the problem for me:

```
<span class="date">
  {{ record.created_at | date:"MMM d, y h:mm" }}{{ record.created_at | date:"a" | lowercase }}
</span>
```

Produces: Dec 18, 2017 4:52pm

Comment: If you need this in multiple places, I'd recommend [implementing a custom pipe](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-date-pipe-formatting-date-times-in-angular-with-examples/#creating-custom-date-pipe-in-angular) so that the ugly logic can be hidden there.

Answer (score 2):

use  [`| lowercase`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/lowercase)

```
{{item.date | date: 'h:mma, dd MMM y' | lowercase}}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
 }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    {{date | date:'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm a' | lowercase}}<br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good idea but it also changes `Jan` to `jan` which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: ok, so it seems like this is a known issue without a proper fix